# Are configuration manger Dll's Redistributable

Tags: c#, sccm

Hi I have a C# project that runs a couple of WQL queries against SCCM.

We want to be able to distribute it with our code but cant seem to find the licencing around it or any NuGet packages with it in.

The DLL's used are:
`Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.dll`
`Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.dll`
(or `AdminUI.WqlQueryEngine.dll`)

The references i need to resolve are:

```
WqlConnectionManager, IResultObject & SmsQueryException
```

Any thing i seem to find refers to Configuration Manager SDK but i cant find it to download.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ebf4f2d4-2502-4357-bcc3-101435dd98d1/where-can-i-download-this-dll-microsoftconfigurationmanagementmanagementproviderwqlqueryengine?forum=configmgrgeneral

Comment: Thanks for this, I know the dll's are installed as part of the admin console but there is nothing about re-distributing them or any link to download the SDK.

Comment: https://www.autoitconsulting.com/site/sccm-sdk/fundamentals/configuring-visual-studio-to-use-sccm-assemblies/

Comment: Keep in mind that if you really only use basic wmi (not something like query for an application and translate it to a modifyable object or something complicated) you do not need those dlls. There are lots of examples on how to do wmi queries on sccm in ps or vbs (which do not need dlls) and you can of course do it the same way in c# as well